# useMemo causes hook to continuously fire infinitely

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom react hook that I wrote to query data from a subgraph endpoint. It simply returns an array of objects.

```
const useAllLPTokens = (): GraphQLResponse<LPTokens> => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<number>(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<any>();
    const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>();
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState<LPTokens | undefined>();

    const getLPTokenData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(subgraphEndpoint,
                {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    query: graphQuery
                }
            );
            setStatus(res.status);
            setResponse(res)
            setPayload(res.data)
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error)
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useMemo(() => {
        getLPTokenData();
    }, [])

    return { status, loading, error, response, payload }
}
```

Component where it is used:

```
const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
    const { account } = useActiveWeb3React();

    const { status: status1, loading: loading1, error: error1, response: response1, payload: payload1 } = useAllLPTokens();
    console.log(payload1);
    ...
```

I'm not sure why when I use `useMemo` in the hook, it fires endlessly when I check the browser console. However when I use `useEffect` it doesn't. I didnt include any dependency for `useMemo` and I assumed it will only fire once when it is called. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `useMemo()` without the dependencies array will calculate the value on every render.

See this link for reference

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

> If no array is provided, a new value will be computed on every render.

Comment: Understood, however when I added dependencies `[ status, loading, error, response, payload ]` it still fires infinitely?

Comment: when you add dependencies `loading`, useMemo calculate `getLPTokenData()` and `setLoading` being call so `loading` continue change and useMemo recalculate again

Comment: Exactly as @NgheMinh said - you're modifying the dependency inside of the `useEffect` hook (inside of the `getLPTokenData()` call) so you're creating an infinite loop